# 1990s/80s movie about some kind of law enforcement group from the future that goes back into the past to "reverse" their targets

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I watched this movie back in the late 90s. It's probably a lesser-known, US-made film. The plot starts with bad guys: a group of three or four strangers, supposedly from the future, who track down certain targets that committed crimes in their time.

One person from this group is a woman with a set of robotic arms attached to her shoulders (I think this is not a permanent fixture; she can take them off). She uses them to immobilize the target while the "justice" is being served. She might also have been a person of color, but I'm not 100% certain.

I think their first target was a boy or a young man. After he is caught, they briefly explain the verdict and then proceed with his execution by gradually "reversing" him to the point of non-existence - the same way as they do with all of their targets.

When they try to apprehend one of their next targets - a girl in her 20s/30s - she somehow escapes and then the story goes as in every action movie in the 90s - she calls some dude, he joins the fight, and bad guys lose.

I don't remember the ending, but I remember that the girl with robotic arms while fighting one of the protagonists gets "reversed" herself.

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Past Perfect](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117308/)*** (1996)...?

> A cop (Roberts) tries to bust a gang of teenage gun dealers. In the process he catches only one and tries to charge him with a number of offences but fails since the gang member is underage. One by one the youth's friends start turning up dead. It is up to Dylan (Roberts), and his partner to save the youth from the same fate as the rest of his gang.

From what I can gather, the plot involves three time travellers -- Stone (Nick Mancuso), Bookkeeper (Saul Rubinek) and Zoe (Marcie Mellish) -- who've come back in time to execute four teenagers -- Blade, Skull, Shy Girl and Rusty -- for crimes they'll commit in the future.

These teenagers are criminals in the present as well, and are also being pursued by a pair of 20th century cops -- Dylan Cooper (Eric Roberts) and Ally Marsey (Laurie Holden) -- although they just want to arrest the teens, not kill them. When some of the teens start turning up dead, Cooper and Marsey do their best to protect the ones who're still alive.

Zoe is a black woman with a mechanical right arm.

> [image: Image of a woman with a mechanical right arm, from "Past Perfect" (1996).]
>
> <sub>*Past Perfect* (1996)</sub>

According to a [review](https://www.explosiveaction.com/2012/03/past-perfect-1996.html) I found, the arm is something she puts on, rather than a permanent attachment.

> The woman with the mechanical arm, Zoe (Marcie Mellish) was a good hitman. The mechanical arm is not explained (though we see her putting it on) but it added some believable braun to her otherwise slim physique.

The same review mentions that the time travellers taser the teens to death (rather than reverse-ageing them into nonexistence), which is why there are bodies left for the 20th century cops to discover. However, it also notes that in order to travel back in time, you have to be encased in a protective shield, and if that shield breaks, then you revert to the age you should be in the current year. As a result, one of the time travellers ends up turning into a child, then a baby, then vanishing into their clothing.

> The science of the movie dictates that to travel back in time you need to be completely encased in a protective shield (a transparent glue), and if it breaks, you revert to the age you should be in the current year. If you aren't born yet, which is the case for one of the future-cops, you turn into a child, then a baby, and then vanish into your clothing!

Answer (score 4):

The film Millenium from 1989 is a partial match for what you describe, enough to make me wonder if you conflating two films or simply misremembering.

In particular it heavily features time travel and does have a female character who is part cyborg.

You can watch the trailer here...

more information on the TVtropes page here... **https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Millennium1989**

Comment: The other half sounds a bit like *Looper*.

Comment: Actually my very first thought was the Inquisitor episode of Red Dwarf!